# What are the best practices when using classnames, ids and data-attributes in React

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, custom-data-attribute

I have built a big app using React and it's getting quite difficult to debug (I also use styled-components), and I want a way to quickly identify elements and components when inspecting the dom.

Styled components generate a random hash, that means it's difficult to locate the exact component sometimes.

I was wondering if people can advise if using ids, classes or data-attributes (or a combination was best) and as the identifiers are mainly gonna be used for debugging and tests, if there was a good way to rip these out of the production bundle? Maybe using webpack or another alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Styled Components comes with a Babel Plugin that you can use for better debugging. 
You can install it with:

```
npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-styled-components
```

You can [add it to babel config](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/tooling#usage) like:

```
{
  "plugins": ["babel-plugin-styled-components"]
}
```

This will show the name of the styled component prefixed with the filename in React DevTools. This can help with all the `styled.DOMNode` appearing in your devtools.

From the [docs](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/tooling#better-debugging):

> adds support for showing your components' real name in the React
>   DevTools. Consider writing a styled component that renders a button
>   element, called MyButton. It will normally show up as 
>   for all of your components, but with this plugin they show .

Docs also specify options to configure these like `displayName` and `fileName` that can you can find [here](http://adds%20support%20for%20showing%20your%20components'%20real%20name%20in%20the%20React%20DevTools.%20Consider%20writing%20a%20styled%20component%20that%20renders%20a%20button%20element,%20called%20MyButton.%20It%20will%20normally%20show%20up%20as%20%3Cstyled.button%3E%20for%20all%20of%20your%20components,%20but%20with%20this%20plugin%20they%20show%20%3CMyButton%20/%3E.)

Comment: this looks good to be fair. but would rather not add another package if poss. but will look into it. in your opinion if i just tried to use data-attributes, would that work?

Comment: @TheDecimator If you add `data` attributes to your html which by your words is already big, it would increase your bundle size and need constant maintenance,  You would need more packages and configs to remove them during production.